# Can video feed be used to track location of an IP?

Tags: web-browser, user-tracking

I don't know if it is possible, but I have read that while a user is viewing a video, the location of user can be traced without sharing its knowledge to the user. Even when user has disabled the option to allow tracking for websites.
Is it possible? If yes how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The streaming server needs to know *where* to send the video to, thus it is aware of your IP address.

Using this IP address, your estimated position can be requested from a so-called geolocation database (which connects networks to locations). This usually is not accurate to street or house level, but most of the time at least resolves the city and country you're in.

You can only prevent this using a proxy or VPN server, so your actual IP address is hidden behind it (and you will be located around wherever the proxy is located physically).

Comment: So if I have a proxy then tracking is not possible?

Comment: Not based on geolocation databases. If a site uses JavaScript and browser APIs to resolve your location and you allow that, obviously it will be able to do so anyway. Be also aware of cookies and other browser fingerprinting technologies, so a website _could_ remember who (and thus where) you are.

Comment: It's also worth noting that if your adversary has privileged information, e.g. access to your traffic, most proxy solutions (e.g. HTTP or SOCKS proxies) will not protect you. A VPN solution is more appropriate if you're using an untrusted network (e.g. hotel wifi) or are worried about your ISP seeing what you're doing.